# What is the meaning of the number printed by __pretty_function__ in Xcode

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am using `__pretty_function__` when logging, and would like to understand the relevance and meaning of the number that is sometimes printed. I believe `__pretty_function__` was originally part of GCC, but it seems to be a slightly modified version in Xcode as I can't find mention of this number elsewhere.

E.g.

```
2015-11-09 23:40:24.743 AppName[50505:5730066] -[CASMainViewController initialiseMenuStructureInCoreData] Found 0 previous entries in the MenuItem entity
2015-11-09 23:40:24.743 AppName[50505:5730066] __58-[CASMainViewController initialiseMenuStructureInCoreData]_block_invoke Found dictionary key: Section5
```

In the logging above, what is the relevance of "58"? Is this some sort of background thread ID? If so, does this number align with any other debug information elsewhere within Xcode?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like it, given `AppName[50505:5730066]`.

Comment: I don't know what them numbers are either! :-)
Are you able to explain them please?